# Ending an http request prematurely

Tags: node.js

I have a node application with many entry points. All entry points need to fetch a game server, based on a request parameter. If the server does not exist, I want to show the user an error message, and end the request.

```
function getGameServer(gametype, httpResponse) {
    if (gameServers[gametype])
        return gameServers[gametype];
    else 
        httpResponse.end("Unknown game type '"+gametype+"'");
}

....


app.get('/:gametype/beginner', function(req,res) {
    var gameServer = getGameServer(req.params.gametype, res);
    console.log(gameServer.beginner_properties);
    ...
});

app.get('/:gametype/advanced', function(req,res) {
    var gameServer = getGameServer(req.params.gametype, res);
    console.log(gameServer.advanced_properties);
    ...
});
```

The problem is, if the function getGameServer doesn't find a game server, it does not stop after the "end" statement, but returns (with a null value), and so I get a node exception in the "gameServer.beginner_properties" or "gameServer.advanced_properties".

Of course I can check the return value in each ".get" function, however, there are many such functions and it is tedious to check the value in each one.

Is there a way to just end the request from within the getGameServer function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make `getGameServer` a middleware:

```
function getGameServer(req, res, next) {
  var gametype          = req.params.gametype;
  res.locals.gameserver = gameServers[gametype];

  if (! res.locals.gameserver)
    return res.end('Unknown game type "' + gametype + '"'); // end the request
  next(); // this will call the next-in-line handler, which is your route handler below
}

app.get('/:gametype/beginner', getGameServer, function(req, res) {
  console.log('server', res.locals.gameserver);
  ...
});

app.get('/:gametype/advanced', getGameServer, function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

`getGameServer` basically acts as a filter: it ends the request if the game type isn't known, otherwise it will let the request pass so it will get handled by your routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor `getGameServer` to pass it a callback, and only call it if the server exists.

```
function getGameServer(gametype, httpResponse, callback) {
    if (gameServers[gametype])
        callback(httpResponse, gameServers[gametype]);
    else 
        httpResponse.end("Unknown game type '"+gametype+"'");
}
....


app.get('/:gametype/beginner', function(req,res) {
    getGameServer(req.params.gametype, res, function(res, gameServer) {
        console.log(gameServer.beginner_properties);
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: The idiomatic solution would be for the callback to always be called, and for the first parameter to be the error if there is one. The callback would usually start `if (err) return next(err);`

Comment: @RichardMarr The OP explicitly request not to check for error. But your way is definitely cleaner